# a simple increment register

Tags: syntax-error, verilog

I want to design an increment register that always increases input and put it in output.  I write this code, but it has error:

`# Error: VCP2858 test3.v : (51, 19): in is not a valid left-hand side of a procedural assignment.`

```
module inc(in, out);
 output reg [0:32] out ;
 input [0:32] in ;
 wire [0:32] in ; 
 always @(*)
 begin 
in <=( in + 1);//error
out<=in; 
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Verilog, you should not assign a value to a signal declared as an `input` inside a module.  Your code can be simplified as:

```
module inc(in, out);
 output [0:32] out ;
 input [0:32] in ;
assign out = in + 1; 
endmodule
```